# aapt command works in cmd prompt but not when using Process() in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, process, command-line-arguments, aapt

Hey all I am trying to get this command to work using C#'s Process(();

```
aapt d badging "c:\adb\apks\ftp\ftp.apk" | "C:\adb\grep" package | "c:\adb\sed" -r "s/package: name='([a-z0-9.]*)'.*/\1/"
```

When I run that in my cmd window it works just fine:

[image]

But when I run the same command using the Process() I get the full data:

[image]

The output for the passed Arguments variable looks like this:

[image]

My Process code is this:

```
private string Execute(string Arguments, string msg) {
    string text = null;
    Process p = new Process();

    cmdOutputs.AppendText("Sending: " + Arguments + Environment.NewLine);

    p.StartInfo.FileName = adbPath + "aapt.exe";
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = Arguments.Replace("aapt ","");

    if (!deviceID.Equals("")) {
        //Its the first time we are using the app
        //so we need to get the device ID with
        //using the -s command
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-s " + deviceID + " " + Arguments;
    }

    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    p.Start();

    do {
        Application.DoEvents();

        if (Arguments.Contains("keyevent")) { break; }    
        
        string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        text += output;

        string err = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
        text += err;
    } while (!p.HasExited);

    text += msg;

    cmdOutputs.AppendText("Completed: " + Environment.NewLine);

    cmdOutputs.SelectionColor = Color.Tan;
    cmdOutputs.SelectionFont = new Font(cmdOutputs.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
    cmdOutputs.AppendText(text.Replace("\r\r\n", Environment.NewLine) + Environment.NewLine);
    cmdOutputs.SelectionColor = Color.White;
    cmdOutputs.SelectionFont = new Font(cmdOutputs.Font, FontStyle.Regular);    
    cmdOutputs.SelectionStart = cmdOutputs.TextLength;
    cmdOutputs.ScrollToCaret();

    return text;
}
```

Can anyone spot where I am missing something that's needed?

Comment: You probably want to run `cmd /c <your command line>` in order to allow piping between processes like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @RetiredNinja ths is what needed to be done:

```
private string Execute(string Arguments, string msg) {
    string text = null;
    Process p = new Process();

    cmdOutputs.AppendText("Sending: " + Arguments + Environment.NewLine);

    //p.StartInfo.FileName = adbPath + "aapt.exe";
    //p.StartInfo.Arguments = Arguments.Replace("aapt ","");
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C " + adbPath + "aapt.exe" + Arguments.Replace("aapt ","");

    if (!deviceID.Equals("")) {
        //Its the first time we are using the app
        //so we need to get the device ID with
        //using the -s command
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-s " + deviceID + " " + Arguments;
    }

    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    p.Start();

    do {
        Application.DoEvents();

        if (Arguments.Contains("keyevent")) { break; }    
        
        string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        text += output;

        string err = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
        text += err;
    } while (!p.HasExited);

    text += msg;

    cmdOutputs.AppendText("Completed: " + Environment.NewLine);

    cmdOutputs.SelectionColor = Color.Tan;
    cmdOutputs.SelectionFont = new Font(cmdOutputs.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
    cmdOutputs.AppendText(text.Replace("\r\r\n", Environment.NewLine) + Environment.NewLine);
    cmdOutputs.SelectionColor = Color.White;
    cmdOutputs.SelectionFont = new Font(cmdOutputs.Font, FontStyle.Regular);    
    cmdOutputs.SelectionStart = cmdOutputs.TextLength;
    cmdOutputs.ScrollToCaret();

    return text;
}
```

The addition was:

```
p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C " + Arguments.Replace("aapt ","");
```

Comment: Your answer is helpful, you can mark it so that it can help more people